# Tor is connected not only to guard node

Tags: anonymity

Several times a day I notice that Tor is not only connected to the guard node but also to other IP addresses. Sometimes three or four IP addresses. Is this normal?

Comment: Where are you seeing these connections? (How did you arrive at the conclusion that there are other connections?)

Comment: It is quite hard to give a good answer to this question without more information. As the OP hasn't reacted for half a year I'll close the question. If more information are provided we could reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is normal. tor opens more than one exit nodes so it can connect when needed. Some times it will connect to one web page by two exit nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information, my best guess would be that it connects to directory servers to get an updated consensus.

You can check that the IPs that your Tor connects to are known relays.